How is energy conserved in sound propagation in solids?
I am trying to understand the sound propagation in solids and I ran into an issue. Firstly, I think a solid material that has particles with about zero energy means they all are at their equilibrium positions.

From the image given above, I have named the particles. Suppose that particle 1 has been given some energy and as you know, in sound propagation, particle 1 will transfer its energy to particle 2. First, particle 1 will be decelerated by the field or forces between them and cover some distance. Then particle 1 has about zero energy and particle 2 has all the energy of particle 1 as it has been accelerated by the forces. I know that particle 2 will not have all the energy of particle 1 as some of energy is also transferred to particle 3 when particle 1 was transferring energy to particle 2. Since the distance between particle 1 and 2 is less than the equilibrium distance, the forces between them will now repel and accelerate them.
Since particle 1 has already lost all its energy to the particles ahead, how it will return to its original position? I know that it will be repelled by forces but increase in energy of particle 1 will lead to violation of conservation of energy because some energy is created by force, although particle 1 has already transferred all its energy to the particles ahead. Please help me to understand this scenario by imagination or thinking rather than mathematically.

Your image is missing by the way.

Have you seen a Newton’s cradle? Why do you think energy is not conserved?

You should think of the lines between particles as springs. The atomic bonds that connect atoms have an equilibrium length, but they can stretch.

Hi Akshansh and welcome to the Physics SE. At absolute zero the particles are indeed at their equilibrium positions, but for any temp > 0 the particles are vibrating about their equilibrium position with a vibrational energy of about kT. When a particle transfers energy to the next particle along it means that particle cools down slightly i.e. vibrates less, so energy is conserved.

What does "by imagination or thinking" mean?

that is the thing I want to know , how they cool down and go back to their equilibrium positions because as in our school textbooks it is written that after transferring energy to ahead particle it go back to its original positions , to go to its original position  particle should move back and to move anything energy is needed , means here energy is created here . that is problem . I can understand with gas because its the atmospheric pressure or random motion of particle that let them to go back to their position .

@mmesser314
thanks for clarifying this , the image is not perfect but it is like you explain

Vincent Thacker
by mean of imagination or thinking I mean to say not mathematically just explain
